# Why is there no forced signaling during the LOCKED_IN phase of BIP 8(LOT=true)?

Tags: soft-fork, taproot, activation-mechanism, bip8-version-bits

Why is there no forced signaling during the LOCKED_IN phase of BIP 8(LOT=true)?

During the [MUST_SIGNAL phase](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/102585/what-is-the-benefit-of-forced-signaling-in-a-soft-fork-activation-mechanism) of BIP 8(LOT=true) a threshold of miners have to signal. The next phase after MUST_SIGNAL is LOCKED_IN. Signaling in the LOCKED_IN phase is recommended rather than mandatory. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The state transition diagram of BIP 8 is [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0008.mediawiki#state-transitions).

The specific change you refer to was made in this [BIP PR](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/pull/1020) by AJ Towns. Once we move into the LOCKED_IN phase of BIP 8 the soft fork is definitely going to activate at some point and so any requirement to signal is unnecessary. The MUST_SIGNAL phase makes it clear to the network that signaling is being enforced by the network. In the LOCKED_IN phase (which only begins after a difficulty adjustment period, 2016 blocks, where the threshold of signaling has been met) it is clear to the network that the soft fork rules will be enforced in future.